# How to know if a thread was interrupted using JSch

Tags: java, jsch, java-threads, interrupted-exception

I am using `com.jcraft.jsch` library to make remote SFTP sessions. It is a convenient library and easy to use.

While I used the library in a single-threaded scenario no problems arose, but now I am using it inside one of many threads in my application.

The problem I found is Jsch seems to trap `InterruptedException` before my own code, just to rethrow it as a different exception,  `SftpException` or `JschException`.

If I pretend that any `SftpException` and `JschException` came from an `InterruptedException` then I can gently stop the thread and everything flows fine. However, this is dangerous because I am masking real `SftpException`/`JschException` exceptions due to Internet transmission errors, wrong credentials, etc.

How can I be sure that an `InterruptedException` occurred inside Jsch?

Comment: That said, `SftpException` has a `getCause()` method. If your cause is an `InterruptedException`, well, there you are.

Comment: I am using `jsch-0.1.55.jar`

Comment: Ah! good starting point. Let me see

Comment: Ahh, it's `JSchException` -- capital `S` not lowercase, which is why the grep didn't find anything. Same thing re: having a `getCause()` available.

Comment: Sorry! I typed manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `SftpException` or a `JSchException` is raised to wrap another throwable, its `cause` will be a `Throwable` describing the exception that was wrapped.

Thus, you can check whether `.getCause()` on either of these returns an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trapping `com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException` but its cause is printing `null`. I am using `logger.severe(e.getCause().getMessage());`

Comment: Ok, I see, I have to use `e.getCause().toString()`

Comment: I would use the `instanceof` operator. `e.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException` -- no `getMessage()` or `toString()` required.